# Adding a background image in pygames?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a project we have to create a video game using pygames and I am having trouble with my background image. I can't get it to display behind my players nor the score. Should I use screen.blit or should I use screen.fill? Any help appreciated.

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)

pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load('grand-metropolis.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.7)


SCR_WID, SCR_HEI = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCR_WID,SCR_HEI), 0, 16)
pygame.display.set_caption("Ever Emerald")
font = pygame.font.SysFont("white", 32)

bg = pygame.image.load("sddefault.jpg")


class Player():
        def __init__(self, SCR_WID, SCR_HEI,):

                self.x, self.y = SCR_WID, SCR_HEI/2 
                self.speed = 3
                self.padWid, self.padHei = 8, 64
                self.score = 0
                self.scoreFont = pygame.font.Font("imagine_font.ttf", 64)

        def scoring(self, screen, cord, winner):

                scoreBlit = self.scoreFont.render(str(self.score), 1, (255, 255, 255))
                screen.blit(scoreBlit, (cord, 16))

                if self.score == 10:
                        print (winner) 
                        exit()

        def movement(self, up, down):

                keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                if keys[up]: 
                        self.y -= self.speed
                elif keys[down]:
                        self.y += self.speed

                if self.y <= 0:
                        self.y = 0
                elif self.y >= SCR_HEI-64:
                        self.y = SCR_HEI-64

        def draw(self, screen):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y, self.padWid, self.padHei))
                screen.blit(bg, (640,380))
```

Comment: Use screen.blit

Answer (score 1):

It is just a matter of drawing order.

Take a look at this pseudocode.

```
Draw player.
Draw background.
# Player is not visible.

Draw background.
Draw player
# Desired output
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help you!
[How to add a background image into pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005641/how-to-add-a-background-image-into-pygame)
Tell me if that worked! And `screen.blit()` would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
def draw(self, screen):
    screen.blit(bg, (640,380))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y, self.padWid, self.padHei))
```

I haven't been able to analyze your code much, but this should fix the issue.

When you tell the computer to blit an image, it blits it regardless of what is behind it.  It doesn't care; you told it to put an image there, so it is going to put an image there.  You first displayed the players.  No problems here.  But you then told it to display the background AFTER you displayed the players.  This displays the background screen, regardless of what was behind it.

Refer to http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit