# Pygame - adding background image

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to python and created a small game. I want to add a background image, but is is not working. The image is not displayed.

i tried it with the following code:

```
background = pygame.image.load("images\\background.png")
screen.blit(background,(0,0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the question does not really illustrate the problem.  But if the code is generating the error:

> background = pygame.image.load('images/background.png')
>   pygame.error: Couldn't open images/background.png

Then it is simply that PyGame can't find the specified image file.

However I expect that your code is simply not "flushing" the updates to the window / screen with a call to `pygame.display.flip()`

```
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH      = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT     = 400

### MAIN
pygame.init()
SURFACE = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE
window  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Background Image")

background_image = pygame.image.load('images/grass.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True

    # Movement keys
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
        print("up")
    #elif ...

    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    window.blit( background_image, ( 0,0 ) )
    pygame.display.flip()                    # <-- Flush drawing ops to the screen

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop( 60 )

pygame.quit()
```

Note the 4th-last line.

Comment: i really just forgot to update the display Surface with pygame.display.flip(). Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005641/how-to-add-a-background-image-into-pygame) page on StackOverflow. It has multiple solutions that you can use. I'll write one of them here.

You can make an image the size of your game window, then before anything else is displayed, blit it to (0,0).

```py
bg = pygame.image.load("background.png")

#INSIDE OF THE GAME LOOP
gameDisplay.blit(bg, (0, 0))

#OTHER GAME ITEMS
```

I hope this helps you!